# Javascript setinterval() sets variables to null after the first run of the function

Tags: javascript, php, html, scope, setinterval

I am trying to get the output of a iframe B in a page A to a div in Page A. I wrote the following code:

```
function FuncExec() {
    todorNamespace = {};
    todorNamespace.nan = true;
    todorNamespace.i = 0;
    todorNamespace.div = document.getElementById("render_frame");
    todorNamespace.iframe = document.getElementById('iframe_exec');
    var pathArray = window.location.href.split('/');
    var protocol = pathArray[0];
    var host = pathArray[2];
    var url = 'http://' + host;
    var src = url + '?q=exec_command';
    // div.appendChild(iframe);
    todorNamespace.iframe.setAttribute("src", src);
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        myPrint()
    }, 200, this);
    function myPrint() {
        var text;
        var body = todorNamespace.iframe.contentDocument.body;
        if (body != null) {
            text = body.innerHTML;
        }
        if (text != null) {
            var logs = text.split("\n");
        }
        if (logs != undefined) {
            if (logs[todorNamespace.i] != "</pre>NaN"
                    && logs[todorNamespace.i] != undefined) {
                todorNamespace.div.innerHTML = todorNamespace.div.innerHTML
                        + logs[todorNamespace.i] + "</br>";
                todorNamespace.i++;
            } else if (logs[todorNamespace.i] == "</pre>NaN") {
                todorNamespace.div.innerHTML = todorNamespace.div.innerHTML
                        + "</pre>";
                clearInterval(interval);
            } else {
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it prints the first line from the iframe and then dies with error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null at line 19
```

I checked with the debugger, but after the second start of the function myPrint() the variables todorNamespace.iframe and todorNamespace.div are becoming null. Why is that happening and can i fix the reading problem?
My Iframe B is a php page, which is printing output at rate 2-3 lines per second that is the php code:

```
while ( @ ob_end_flush () )
        ; 
    $proc = popen ( "myBashCommand", 'r' );
    echo '<pre>';
    while ( ! feof ( $proc ) ) {
        echo fread ( $proc, 4096 );
        @ flush ();
    }
    echo '</pre>';
    @ flush ();
    echo 'NaN';
```

Which suggests that I cannot wait until the page is generated once and then print the output, but need it in "real time", hence that iteration with setInterval to get the text from the iframe. Any ideas how to implement it?

Comment: Make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: here is it:
http://jsfiddle.net/amt1vcgd/ 
Note that at line 11 of the js it should put the address of the iframe, and this is generated on the server, so it wont do as expected